# Create HDR image using opencv in C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

Hi I'm new in C# and i need to create a HDR in C# using Emgu CV library. I get image from binary file. Need To merge two images vertically (one on top of the other) this two images in one image. Please help me to solve the problem.

```
Mat imageToPross = img.Mat;
Rectangle roi1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, imageToPross.Width, imageToPross.Height / 2);
Rectangle roi2 = new Rectangle(0, imageToPross.Height / 2, imageToPross.Width, imageToPross.Height / 2);
Mat currImage = imageToPross.Clone();
Mat result = new Mat(currImage, roi1);
Mat result2 = new Mat(currImage, roi2);
Mat[] images = { result, result2 };
MergeMertens merge_mertens = new MergeMertens();
merge_mertens.Process( images, fusion);
```

In merge_mertens i get error cannot convert from Mat to InputArray